# Ordenar un Queryset de Django por un campo del meta

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo el siguiente modelo :

```
class RejectionJustification(Base):

justification = models.CharField('Justificación', max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.justification

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Motivo de rechazo de gestión"
    verbose_name_plural = "Motivos de rechazo de gestión"
```

Cuando hago un queryset desde una vista necesito que los registros me queden ordenados por la fecha de creació, la cual esta guardada en un campo de la meta del modelo llamado "created_at" asi :

```
management = models.RejectionJustification.objects.filter(justification = 'Aprobada').order_by('created_at')
```

Pero, me arroja error diciendo que el modelo no posee el campo "created_at", asumo que es por ser del meta, pero como podria entonces referenciarlo para el ordenamiento ?, mil gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes mostrar tu clase meta?

Comment: Te sirve algo como esto??? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#get-latest-by . fijate que es para usar en Manager. Sino en ordering  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#ordering donde dice que puedes usar querys You can also use query expressions. para ordenar.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás en un vista generica ListView deberías poner:

```
queryset = RejectionJustification.objects.order_by('justification')
```

o en el meta:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('fields', )
```

Comment: No, porque necesito ordenar por la fecha de creación y no por la justificación y el campo al ser del meta no lo reconoce.

Comment: Puedes fijarte si en tu Tabla existe el campo fecha_creación o algo parecido?

Comment: Existe pero en la meta data , ya que hereda de un modelo base.